# Release Mat inside std::vector

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector, release

Using **OpenCV 2.2**, I am trying to free memory be calling release to a Mat image
inside a std::vector, such as:

```
std::vector < Mat > matVec;
```

However, it seems like

```
for (int k = 0; k < matVec.size(); k++)
{

   matVec[k].release();

}
```

is not releasing any memory (it still compiles, though).

I know there is new memory management in **OpenCV 2.2**, but I couldn't spot the
issue.

A similar example with `IplImage*` type instead of Mat (using `cvReleaseImage()` instead of the Mat member function `.release()`) works just fine.

Any hints?

Answer (score 7):

`.release()` should only be called in exceptional circumstances, it's not for everyday use. Just clear the vector:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat>().swap(matVec);
```

This calls the destructor of each of the `Mat`s, releasing the memory (if no other `cv::Mat` points to it - remember `cv::Mat` is, unlike `IplImage`, a reference-counted datatype. If it is referenced somewhere else, you have to clear that reference too). If you want to keep the vector, but get rid of the contents, replace the `.release()` line in your code with:

```
matVec[k] = cv::Mat();
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob, etarion! I appreciate your help. And how would you do the following: suppose you want to push_back images into matVec. However these images are originally IplImage*. How would you convert from IplImage* to Mat such that the vector can still be properly cleaned, using the method you suggested? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to activate the destructor of each `matVec[k]` object. You can do this by letting `matVec` fall out of scope or by defining `matVec` as a `vector` of `Mat*` and manually allocating and deallocating each object.

This is always safer since OpenCV using a reference counting mechanism for `Mat` objects and so you don't want to deallocate the data in `Mat` directly.